# Why does my Windows-Forms Layout change, when I am opening it from a Console-Application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core

At the beginning of my Project I am starting a Console. After the Console executes my code, a new Form gets open. The Problem the Form looks really strange, not like i designed it in the Editor.

**Form in the Editor, like i designed:**

[image]

**Form after I opened it from the Console-Project:**

[image]

**Code in the Console-Project for opening the Form**

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

**One more thing:** I am using .NET Core 3.1

Anyone has a solution to this problem?

**thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you enabled Windows screen scaling? (Is it a different value then 100%) Right click desktop => Display Settings => Scale and Layout. (I'm asking since the label size is screwed)

Comment: You need to load Win32's Common Controls. Compare the `Main` method from a WinForm's project template vs. a Console project template. You'll also need to set the COM STA thread too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same "theme" you should [EnableVisualStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles?view=netcore-3.1) as the first line in your `main` method. As outlined in the documentation.

Also call [SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault?view=netcore-3.1) with `false` as this is also the default since 2005.

The following are the defaults when creating a new winforms project for dotnet core 3.1

```
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Comment: I haven't used WinForms with .NET Core 3.x yet, but you're saying that the latest version of WinForms right now in 2020 **still** defaults to .NET Framework 1.1's ugly GDI+ text rendering behaviour? wow...

Comment: This is what the template does when you do File => new Project (with .net core 3.1). My guess is they didn't change it for backwards compatibility. Or they didn't want to scare some of the old school developers.

Comment: Yeah, I expected that (given Microsoft's commendable commitment to backwards-compatibility) - but part of me was still hoping they'd start making breaking-changes to remove old cruft like that.